# Javascript -adding a function with a paramenter to addEventListener causes the function to fire

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to pass the index of a `forEach()` function into a functions argument inside of `addEventListener` like so:

```
dispensaryLocations.forEach((location, i) => {
  location.addEventListener('click', clickLocationToOpenMarker(i));
});
```

Here is the `clickLocationToOpenMarker()` function:

```
  const clickLocationToOpenMarker = id => {
    infoWindowContents.map(infowindow => {
      infowindow.close();
    });
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[id], 'click');
  };
```

For contex: `markers` is an array of Google Maps markers that when clicked, open an infowindow displaying info about the location. `infoWindowContents` is an array that holds all of the corresponding infowindows for each marker. However I am not concerned with the Google Maps API here, it's more of a concern of trying to pass an argument to the function inside of `addEventListener` without it firing.

My issue is that when I pass the function to `addEventListener` like this: `element.addEventListener('click' clickLocationToOpenMarker)` the function is assigned to each element as expected, and is not immediately invoked and ran.

The caveat here is that I need to be able to pass the `i` variable as an argument to the function like so: `element.addEventListener('click', clickLocationToOpenMarker(i))` so that the function knows which `Google Maps Marker` to open. However once I add the argument to the function's parameter, unlike in the example directly above, the function is invoked and fired immediately on each iteration of the `forEach()` loop.

Why does `addEventListener` fire a function immediately when an argument is passed, but when there is no argument passed to the function, it just assigns it?

Comment: `functionname(something)` is a **call** to the function, not a reference to the function. It's not being "fired" by `addEventListener()`; it's called before `addEventListener()` is called because you're passing the return value of a function call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are invoking `clickLocationToOpenMarker`. You need to wrap it in a function to prevent it from running immediately:

```
dispensaryLocations.forEach((location, i) => {
  location.addEventListener('click', () => clickLocationToOpenMarker(i));
});
```

Comment: saved me from sitting here at work for the next 30 minutes. Thank you so much, this was a huge oversight on my part.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `clickLocationToOpenMarker(i)` is function invocation. To bind the function to click event, you can wrap it in another anonymous function (as sliptype explains in their answer):

```
location.addEventListener('click', function() {
    clickLocationToOpenMarker(i);
});
```

Or, you can use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to bind the parameter value in the function (so you don't have to create the anonymous function).

```
location.addEventListener('click', clickLocationToOpenMarker.bind(null, i));
```